# VB.net: Remove item from generic list does not work

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5

I am using VB.net and am trying to remove an object item from a list like so:

```
Dim evidenceContentItems As List(Of ContentData) = contentApi.GetList(contentCriteria)

For Each item As ContentData In evidenceContentItems.ToList()

    Dim contentMetaList() As Ektron.Cms.CustomAttribute = metaApi.GetContentMetadataList(item.Id).AttributeList

    For Each metaItem As CustomAttribute In contentMetaList.ToList()

        If metaItem.Value <> "-1" Then                
            evidenceContentItems.Remove(item)
        End If

    Next
Next
```

If I put a QuickWatch on the "evidenceContentItems.Remove(contentItem)" command, it returns True but the count of items in the list does not go down and the item is not actually removed.

The only other thing I can think of doing is to create a second list and add valid items to it instead, but I would like to understand why .remove does not work (and yet returns True).

**EDIT:**

So it seems that by calling .ToList() I am making a copy and thus when I .Remove() I am removing from the copy.  I added .ToList() as it is not possible to remove an item from a list while you are iterating through it.

Have also tried:

```
    For Each item As ContentData In itemsToRemove
        If evidenceContentItems.Contains(item) Then
            evidenceContentItems.Remove(item)
        End If
    Next
```

Again I get a True return from .Remove(item) but still the count does not go down.

Comment: "item"  is an object.  you get item from copy but not equal original item.

Comment: Tell more about `ContentData`. Is it a value type or a reference type? Did you override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`?

Comment: ContentData is an object from a Content Management System.  I have not overidden Equals or GetHashCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wasn't able to successfully Remove an item from a list.  In the end I created a new list to add items instead.  I created a new list called itemsToShow:

```
Dim itemsToShow As New List(Of ContentData)
```

Then as I loop through evidenceContentItems, I add items that I would have otherwise not removed:

```
itemsToShow.Add(item)
```

I get the whole thing about removing a copy - but in my edited question above I tried to remove from the original but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

`Remove` doesn't work because the `item` does not reference the same object in memory as the one you're trying to remove from the list.

One option is to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in the `ContentData` class so that two objects can be considered as "equal" even though they are not the same.

You can also use the `RemoveAll` method which doesn't require changes to the `ContentData` class:

```
evidenceContentItems.RemoveAll(Function(x) x.Id = itemToRemove.Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post. But I just wanted to share what worked for me. Using ToArray instead of ToList() work for me.

```
For Each item As ContentData In evidenceContentItems.ToArray()
    evidenceContentItems.Remove(item)
Next
```